# Lawyer request change in Court proceedings by defendant or plaintiff

Tags: lawyer, judge, judiciary

According to the law, can a defendant or Plaintiff  change his/her lawyer after certain court proceedings in both civil/criminal cases.

Example.

A Court is adjourned and given a certain date for next proceeding.

Now the Plaintiff or Defendant would like to change his/her lawyer giving reasonable reasons for the same.
Reasons could be : Personal emergency call for the Lawyer, Lawyer falling sick/unwell etc

Is this allowed in the judiciary? If yes, what are the rules? Who gives the permission grant to either the defendant or plaintiff to change the lawyer? Is it the Judge or panel of Judges?

Comment: Are you sure you mean Dependant and not *Defendant*?

Comment: And... rules of court can vary around the world so what jurisdiction (country, province, state etc) does this relate to?

Comment: Can you provide inputs in US, UK courts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Once a trial has started, a lawyer can only be replaced with leave of the court

The judge will consider the reason and where the case is at, and if they are satisfied that the replacement is in the interest of justice, they will give that leave.

Before that, there is no limitation.